# map multiple value to one in a dict python

Tags: python, postgresql, python-3.x, google-bigquery

I want to move some data from postgres to BigQuery.

For this I can query the postgres table to get the schema, then I map data types.

```
lookup = {
    'char': 'STRING',
    'character': 'STRING',
    'varchar': 'STRING',
    'character varying': 'STRING',
    'text': 'STRING'}
```

My question is, can I do this in such a way that I can provide a list(or tuple of values that correspond to STRING.

Something like, at a very psueudocode level:

```
lookup = {
      lambda x: if x in ['char', 'character' ... ] : 'STRING' else if x in ['int'] : 'INTEGER' else None
}
```

That will return the data type

```
lookup['char']
> STRING
```

Comment: I wonder: Why?

I only see the result ending up harder to read.

But there are a few options
`lookup = {...}; for key in [...]:;  lookup[key] = 'STRING';`
or 
`lookup.update({key: 'STIRNG' for key in [...]})` for example.

Comment: Why would you want to? It seems like the first solution is functional?

Comment: Simply to make the solution more succinct.

Answer (score 1):

While I agree with the comments asking *Why?*, you can do this if you think it is nicer, and it's not too hard to read:

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> lookup = defaultdict(lambda: 'STRING', int='INTEGER')
>>> lookup['int']
'INTEGER'
>>> lookup['char']
'STRING'
>>> lookup['varchar']
'STRING'
```